# Rows per page on IG (Interactive Grid) Apex Oracle

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, apex

Interactive grid doesn't have option to put rows per page on click(over options) like IR(Interactive report) like this:
[image]

How to enable this on IG ? maybe with javascript initialization code or something?

Does someone have solution or has been in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting under for the interactive grid (tested on 20.2) called "Pagination". If the type is set to "scroll", which is the default, then indeed you won't have the option to set the rows per page. If it is set to "Page", then the option to set a nr of rows per page is available, just like for interactive grid. No custom coding is needed to achieve this.